# How to use 'hasManyThrough' with more than 3 tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database

as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) the current **hasManyThrough** can be used when u have something like `country > users > posts`

which result in something like `Country::whereName('xx')->posts;`
which is great but what if i have more than that like

`country > cities > users > posts`
or even

`country > cities > towns > users > posts`

how would you then implement something like that so you can write the same as above

`Country::whereName('xx')->posts;` or `Town::whereName('xx')->posts;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly there is no one easy solution, so heres what i found

1- add the other table foreign id into the post table and stick to the **hasMany** & **belongsTo**, ex.

```
posts
    id - integer
    country_id - foreign
    // etc...
    title - string
```

2- go with the **hasManyThrough** on each table except `user` & `post` as there is no need unless you want to go deeper, ex.

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

cities
    id - integer
    country_id - foreign
    name - string

towns
    id - integer
    city_id - foreign
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    town_id - foreign
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - foreign
    title - string
```

> - so lets try with the 2nd option

1- set up your **hasMany** & **belongsTo** relations as usual

2- setup the **hasManyThrough** on the models.

3- to achieve the above example of `Country::whereName('xx')->posts` we add another method to the **country** model

```
// because Country::find($id)->towns, return an array
// so to get all the posts we have to loop over that
// and return a new array with all the country posts
public function posts()
{
    $posts = [];

    foreach ($this->towns as $town) {
        $posts[] = $town->posts;
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

4- as the whole thing is working through the **foreign_id** so we search by the ***id*** instead of the ***name*** like `Country::find($id)->posts()`

Answer (score 11):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Country extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Post::class, [City::class, Town::class, User::class]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this package. I require this to one of my packages.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've done. I did some modification to @ctfo's answer, so it will return as collection.

```
public function posts()
{
    $posts = collect();

    foreach ($this->towns->get() as $town) {
        $post = $town->posts();
        if ( $post->count() ) $posts = $posts->merge( $post );
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

I hope this can help anyone who came through.