# Laravel Polymorphic belongsToThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have there tables:

```
// Itinerary
id

// Location
id

// Popup
id

// Poi
id
itinerary_id
poiable_id
poiable_type

// Hotspot
id
content_id
content_type
```

A Itinerary hasMany Locations and Popups through POI (poiable, polymorphic)

```
class Itinerary extends Model {
...
  public function pois()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Poi');
  }

  public function popups()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Popup', 'poiable', 'poi');
  }

  public function locations()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Location', 'poiable', 'poi');
  }
}
```

Locations and Popups hasMany Hotspots (polymorphic via content_id, content_type). A Hotspot holds coords. A location or popup can be opened from multiple angles in an itinerary but holds the same information.

`itinerary -> poi -> location or popup -> hotspot`

What I'm trying to do is to return all the hotspots of an itinerary, it must be a Relation to keep existing code intact.

Something in the line of:

```
function hotspots() {
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Hotspot', 'App\Models\Poi', 'itinerary_id', 'content_id', 'id', 'poiable_id')->join('poi', 'hotspot.content_type', '=', 'poi.poiable_type')
}
```

but can't get it to work (`Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:`)

Comment: Can `poiable_type` only refer to `Location` and `Popup`?

Comment: yes, I thought it was easier that way. But I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947862/how-to-use-hasmanythrough-with-more-than-3-tables-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join the `poi` table, that's already done by the relationship (hence the error):

```php
public function hotspots()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Hotspot::class, Poi::class, 'itinerary_id', 'content_id', 'id', 'poiable_id'
    )->whereColumn('hotspot.content_type', '=', 'poi.poiable_type');
}
```

Comment: Thanks the `whereColumn` did the trick! I used `join` because `where` did not work.